# cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(name: String, balance: Double)'

Tags: string, swift, syntax-error

In the following code i am trying to figure out why the 2 lines at the end are showing up as errors.

```
var account1 = ("State bank personal, 1011.10")
var account2 = ("State bank business, 24309.63")

func deposit(amount : Double, account : (name : String, balance : Double)) -> (String, Double) {
    let newBalance : Double = account.balance + amount
    return (account.name, newBalance)
}

func withdraw(amount : Double, account : (name : String, balance : Double)) -> (String, Double) {
    let newBalance : Double = account.balance - amount
    return (account.name, newBalance)
}

var mondayTransaction = deposit
var fridayTransaction = withdraw

let mondayBalance = mondayTransaction(300.0, account1)
let fridayBalace = fridayTransaction(1200.0, account2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You first two lines have no balance.  You included the amount as part of the name.  Try this:

```
var account1 = ("State bank personal", 1011.10)
var account2 = ("State bank business", 24309.63)
```